# SharePoint Online CORS

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to access SharePoint Online (SPO) programmtically from a local html page on my pc. There arise serveral questions (not sufficient answered when searching the web):

1. Is there from a developers point of view any difference between SharePoint Online and an Office 365 SharePoint teamsite?
2. Is SPO out of the box CORS enabled?
3. Is it possible to access SPO via REST API or JSOM from a local html page? If yes: Is there a working code snippet available esp. with authentication. All results I found searching the web describe problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Not that I know.
2. No it is not CORS enabled. The real issue is caused by the browser and not the server.
3. Local HTML Files are not supported but you can use a local web server.

I use this pattern a lot in Office 365 and SharePoint online. To code javascript I have my local web server running and only reference the scripts from my local server and use it like a CDN.

You will have a web server too be because you cannot directly embed the file use file:/// or anything like this.
CORS is not really the problem in your case it has something to do with the different protocols because you might have your local server running it use mostly http why SharePoint Online is running on https.

I this case your browser need to support displaying mixed Zones. What I have experienced is that it doesn't work with IE because this prohibits the execution of the script.
FireFox i'm not so sure about but you can surely disable the security for localhost.
For Google Chrome a extension is available that disable the security for CORS calls. It is named "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" and you can enable or disable CORS where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, there is no difference
2. Yes, it is supported
3. Yes, you would use ADAL JS and use the token in a REST API call to SharePoint. Here is an example using jQuery including walkthrough instructions for registering your app in Azure: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-jQuery-CORS